# Hadoop Combiner inputs and outputs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My understanding is that a combiner may get called 0 or more times. It seems to me that this has certain implications:

1. It is possible that the combiner never gets called, so the output type of the mapper must match the input type of the reducer.
2. Because it can be called at least once, the combiner input type must match the mapper output type, and the combiner output type must match the reducer input type.
3. Because it can be called multiple times, the combiner input type must match the combiner output type?

The last point I am not 100% sure about. I assume the idea is that the combiner can be called with partially combined data (produced from a previous combiner invocation?).

So that being said, it seems that if you want to use a combiner, then the mapper must output a data type that is capable of representing combined data.
The combiner must be able to accept both output from the mapper and output from a previous invocation of the combiner. The reducer should accept either the output of the mapper or the combiner (which should be of the same type).

Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error if the combiner class inputs don't match the outputs? Unless you're running map-only job, then yes, mappers should "output data capable of being aggregated" (AKA _reduced_). Otherwise, kinda defeats the purpose of the framework

Comment: This was a conceptual question, so no specific error. The question wasn't around whether the data is capable of being aggregated, but whether the data type of the output should be such that it may have already been aggregated. If you read though the question, then you will hopefully get what I am asking.

Comment: A mapper can output whatever it wants, as long as it's serializable by the framework. Try some examples and see if your hypothesis is correct. The main reason a combiner is used is to reduce the IO during shuffle/sort phase